# #How to Run Angular 2 Webpack App in EC2

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2, npm, webpack, package.json

I have an **AngularJs 2** application working in **development mode**
being served by

```
webpack-development-server
```

I wish to host this on EC2.

I have:
- created a **linux** instance
- installed **node** and **npm**
- **cloned my repo** from git
- ran

```
npm install
```

from root where package.json is.
- ran

```
npm start
```

but nothing happens.
Upon visiting the Amazon Public DNS Address,
I get an error:

[image]

***Not Sure what I'm missing!

Help Please***

**package.json** is:

[image]

**Webpack common/production** is:

[image]
[image]

**tsconfig.json** is:

[image]

Comment: Have you got the dist folder present or just source?

Comment: ./dist is there with all .js/.map/index.html files. Not sure why I can't get through.

Comment: Do you have http-server installed?

Comment: Within *scripts* in **package.json** in *postinstall* I did : **sudo npm install -g htt-server**

Comment: I see that now and if you run http-server from SSH do you get an error?

Comment: Not sure how to do that?
I just did **npm start** which starts http-server **in command line** within EC2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130558/discussion-between-j-j-b-and-wowiamhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) globally using `npm install http-server -g`

run

```
sudo http-server dist -a 127.0.0.1 -p 80 --cors
```

because without -p it will default to port `8080` and you are trying port `80` via picture because you are running on port 80 this command will need to be run this under root permissions `sudo` prior to the command.

Replace `127.0.0.1` with your EC2 internal/private IP.

Check if http-server is listening on port 80

```
lsof -n -i:80 | grep LISTEN
```

Comment: I have **installed** http-server **globaly**. I have tried to run **http-server -p 80 but got **Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 0.0.0.0:80**. I also tried running with -a flag and the ec2 public dns address, but got the same error: **Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:80**

Comment: Please try http-server -a 127.0.0.1 -p 80 replace 127.0.0.1 with your private/internal IP address that is assigned to your EC2 instance.

Comment: I ran: **http-server -p 80 -a 54.187.6.116** and I got ** Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 54.187.6.116:80**
Webpack compiles into ./dist, but then it crashes with this error.

Comment: That is your public IP. You can view the private IP on the AWS console.

Comment: Just ran: `http-server -p 80 -a 172.31.11.171` but got: **Error: listen EACCESS 172.31.11.171:80** from *dist* folder.

Comment: That needs to be run under root permissions so use sudo prior to the command.

Comment: I'm up and running! **Thank you!**  
Now the problem is that the **AngularJs 2 is not loading**. The **index.html** filtered to ./dist by Webpack is **rendering properly** with the **script tags** to the **.js generated**. But the actual app that works perfectly in development, does not load in production.

Comment: Is there a reason why it's including files from ../src/app... in your index.html? What are your entry points set in webpack?

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely a network connectivity issue, not a problem with your app.

Make sure that:

1. The network ACL is allowing outgoing and incoming traffic on TCP port 80/443.
2. The security group is allowing incoming traffic on TCP port 80/443.
3. Your local firewall (`iptables` in most cases) is configured to allow incoming connections on TCP port 80/443.

Comment: I have checked all 3 instances of your answer and have all settings regarding 1,2 and 3 in order. thanx